# What is a Direct Radiating Collector Amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, microwave, telecommunications

Reading the Space Systems/Loral press release [SSL Achieves Milestone, 100 Satellites Delivered based on the 1300, a Platform for evolution, innovation](http://sslmda.com/html/pressreleases/pr20150914.html) I ran across the sentence(s):

> - It was the first satellite to use a 100-volt bus and **Direct Radiating Collector (DRC) amplifiers**, providing the higher power needed for direct-to-home television.
> - It was the first true high-throughput satellite, an advance which now enables millions of people around the world to have access to high speed broadband.
> - It was the first to reach 20-kW of power, which enables satellite broadcast of today’s HD and UltraHD television.
> - It was the first satellite to provide two-way ground-based beam forming, which increases a satellite’s flexibility to meet changing business requirements.
>     (emphasis added)

I'm trying to imagine an amplifier with the collector attached directly to a feed horn for radiation, but I think at these frequencies traveling wave tubes (TWTs) are used.

**Question:** What is a Direct Radiating Collector Amplifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a TWT ([Traveling Wave Tube](http://www2.l3t.com/eti/products/twt_design.htm)). It is a kind of the vacuum tube technology. It has a cathode and an anode (forming an electron gun), a helical amplification structure, and a **collector**. [It's not a collector of a transistor]. However, instead of standard way to dissipate the collector's heat into spacecraft body by conduction, the collector is designed to cool additionally by [direct radiation](http://www2.l3t.com/eti/pdf/data_sheets/ETI_K-Band%20Space%20TWT%20datasheet.pdf) into outer space. This technique allows to unload the heat transfer into spacecraft body by 50%, see this [L-3 publication](http://dlx.booksc.org/23400000/libgen.scimag23420000-23420999.zip/browse/10.1109/IVEC.2013.6571072.pdf). Some mentioning of "DRC" advantage can be found in this [US patent application](https://www.google.com/patents/US20020068526), paragraph [0044].

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Now that I think about it, TWTs contain an emitter of electrons and a collector of electrons, and there's no reason to associate those terms only with transistors. Radiating heat to space and reducing heat that would have to be managed internally is certainly an important advantage in spacecraft applications.